# Implicit Wait in selenium waits for the page to get loaded or all the elements to get loaded

Tags: selenium

Implicit Wait in selenium waits for the page to get loaded or all the elements to get loaded.
suppose there is a web page, where the page is loaded while some of the web elements are still loading. So in this scenario if we use Selenium Implicit wait, it will wait for the page loading or for all the elements to get loaded.
Please help with this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of them ;)

You can think that implicit wait is something similar to a "timeout" that is aplied to every element you want to interact with (using `findElement()`) before throwing an exception, even the page is completly loaded or not.

Have a look to official [doc](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).